# Error during setup of unity-js-scopes-tool

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, scopes, javascript

I am going to create a Scope for Ubuntu Touch with the Ubuntu SDK.

I used this [JS-Tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/scopes/tutorials/developing-scopes-javascript/).

So I did the installation process within a fresh installation of Ubuntu 15.10 in VirtualBox with the fallowing intructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-api-team/unity-js-scopes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk unity-js-scopes-dev 
unity-js-scopes-tool setup
```

But after running the last command I get these error codes:

```
Setup started.
W: No chroots are defined in ‘/etc/schroot/schroot.conf’ or ‘/etc/schroot/chroot.d’
E: source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf: Chroot not found
Command returned 1: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf -- echo 1
W: No chroots are defined in ‘/etc/schroot/schroot.conf’ or ‘/etc/schroot/chroot.d’
E: source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.10-armhf: Chroot not found
Command returned 1: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.10-armhf -- echo 1
Remounting chroots ...
Could not connect to click-chroot-agent service
Setup complete.
```

Does anybody know, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I figured it out:

After reading the Tuorials twice I noticed, that I did not add the release PPA for the ubuntu SDK.

Nevertheless I was able to install the ubuntu-sdk. But after added the PPA many new upgrades were available through 'apt-get dist-upgrade'.

Furthermore it was nessesary to create a click target. So my problem was finally solved by a new installation and setup process:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-api-team/unity-js-scopes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk unity-js-scopes-dev 
#NOW create the click target in Ubuntu-SDK's option menu
unity-js-scopes-tool setup
```

The output of 'unity-js-scopes-tool setup' now looks like this:

```
Setup started.
E: source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf: Chroot not found
Command returned 1: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf -- echo 1
E: source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.10-armhf: Chroot not found
Command returned 1: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.10-armhf -- echo 1
Remounting chroots ...
Setup complete.
```

This looks now much better, but not good. I'm going on now to test if JS-Scopes can be created. :-)

Comment: I also have this error, did you ever resolve the problem?

Comment: Hey Jack, I am Sorry, I cannot remember in detail what happened. But I know, that I was finally able to create and compile JS Scopes. I also remember, that I needed to install some further packages, because there was a bug in the SDK. May this is now fixed. Would you please try now to create, compile and run a scope? If it does not work, I am sure, we'll find a solution.